# Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, 2016

I developed visual web part in SharePoint 2013 to get the SPAudit, when build the solution I get error in the SPAuditQuery

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'SPAuditQuery' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I already added the using Microsoft.SharePoint;

```
SPAuditQuery query = new SPAuditQuery(mysiteCollection);
query.SetRangeStart(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
query.SetRangeEnd(DateTime.Now);
```

Please help

Comment: which name space u included in ur code?

Comment: Using Microsoft.SharePoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue usually occurs because of one of below reasons.

1. You are not added the `Microsoft.SharePoint` as a reference to your solution.
2. You are adding `Microsoft.SharePoint` as a reference to your solution **but** not include the name space as `using Microsoft.SharePoint;`
3. Your SharePoint solution is **Sandbox solution** not a **Farm Solution**

> **Note:**
>
> Working with **SPAuditEntry** via SSOM C# requires a **Farm Solution**. it will not work with **Sandbox solution**

---

Based on what you have mentioned in your quest, you already added the `using Microsoft.SharePoint;`

So The most likely reason for this problem is using **SandBox Solution** instead of **Farm Solution**

**To solve your issue, try to switch your solution type to **Farm Solution** by doing the following:**

- In solution explorer, Click on your Project,
- Click F4 to open the Properties.
- Set Sandbox solution to **false**.
- Rebuild your solution, it should be working.

[image]

  -